# Problems with setting up email notifications in Redmine

Tags: email, server, web-applications

I´ve installed a fresh Redmine 2.5.1 installation on a Ubuntu 12.04 server.
Redmine is served by Apache (passenger).

The Server can send emails by use of Postfix (tested with the *mail* command from terminal).

After reading the help document on [Redmine's Email-Configuration](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/EmailConfiguration), I´m confused where to put what though.

My aim is to use the server's ability to send emails with Postfix and not to use an external SMTP like Gmail.

Redmine is also giving me following error in email settings:

[image]

In `/etc/redmine/default` I have following files (no *configuration.yml*!):

- database.yml
- session.yml

In `/usr/share/redmine` resides:

- additional_environment.rb.example
- environment.rb
- locales
- boot.rb
- environments
- routes.rb
- configuration.yml.example
- initializers
- settings.yml

Questions:

1. Which directory is responsible for Redmine's config?
2. Which file is respnsible for email settings?
3. What configuration is needed to use the server's Postfix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. /etc/redmine/
2. /etc/redmine/default/configuration.yml
3. See Below.

`nano -w /etc/redmine/default/configuration.yml`

then paste or type:

```
production:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :sendmail
```

then:

<kbd>CTRL X</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>

For all the possibilities see:
[The Redmine Wiki: Email Configuration](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/EmailConfiguration)